# Get new content from ajax function and replace it on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a single page with a div that gets new content when a user click on a radio button, when the page is loaded it display the main content, when user click on X radio button, that content gets "re-new" or "different" information, there is a DIV id that doesn't change... so... 
When user loads the page, I check fro some values, is X value is lower than then replace the div content, on the first load it works fine, but if the user changes options then the first script wont do nothing... so here is the basic html

```
    <div id="options">
    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:checkOut(this.name,'shipr');" value="1" name="shipping" id="s1">
    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:checkOut(this.name,'shipr');" value="2" name="shipping" id="s2">

<input type="text" id="qty" class="hidden" value="1.2" style="display: none;">

    </div>

    <div id="information">

    <div id="prices>$120.00</div>
    <div id="products">Multiple[...] and tabs long list</div>
    <div id="checkoutbtn">Buy Now</div>

    </div>
```

Basically when user click on any of the radio buttons the content of the div "information" gets replace by ajax information, I'd like to know how do I get the new content and "replace" some values...

Now, the input with the ID qty that is hidden has the value I need is that value is less or grater than I replace the button inside the div with the id checkoutbtn from "buy now" to "Only inside US and UK, please Request a quote"... so, my JS is:

```
(function($) {

        var pkg = $("#qty").val();
        var cot = '<a rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x: 570, y: 550}}" ' +
            'class="modal" href="qut.php">' +
        '<input type="button" value="Quotation" class="btn btn-small">' +
        '</a>';
        window.onload = function() {

            if (pkg < 4 ) {
                // do something
                // alert('Checked');
                $('#checkoutbtn').html(cot);
            }
        };

        $('input:radio[name="shipping"]').change(
            function(){

                if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr("id") == 's1') {

                    // alert(pkg);
                    $('#checkoutbtn').html(cot);
                } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr("id") == 's2') {

                    $('#checkoutbtn').html(cot);
                }
            });

    })(jQuery);
```

When the page is load for the first time it works fine, and if it wasn't for the ajax that change the content of the div with the id information it would be flawless, but is not...

As you can see I have this piece of code: $('input:radio[name="shipping"]').change() ... so now I need something that would give some time to load the new content or to check when the new content is ready and then execute this other code $('#checkoutbtn').html(cot); ... the question is, how do I do that... if I put a timeout of 2 seconds it might work, but sometimes it takes 3 or 5 seconds for the new information to be ready and available to the user and that would be a problem...

So, I need to check when the new content is ready after the user has click on the radio button, how do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Your first two radio buttons have the same value (value = "1"). Might want to fix that first. You also misspelled in  <duv id="checkoutbtn">. Should be 'div', not 'duv'.

Comment: that is not the point but thanks...

Comment: Would be good to see your AJAX function as well, but I can only guess that the event handlers you set are not applied to the new content. Look into re-applying them on your AJAX's success function or make use of jQuery's `.on` with something like `$('.wrapping-element').on('event','.elements', function(){})` (where `.wrapping-element` is something that is not replaced by AJAX).